# Can't use host machine internet after docker installation

Tags: docker

After I install docker.io to my computer(Ubuntu 16.04), the hosts machine internet goes away.
Could anyone help me, how can I use both internet and the installed docker.
I could write this here, because I removed docker, and now it is not on my machine.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can u "ping 8.8.8.8"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to add the following lines into `/etc/docker/daemon.json`:

```
{
  "bip": "172.26.0.1/16"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using VM environments, have you 
 a) set the VM network adapter to dhcp and 
 b) shared your main connection to the VM network adapter?

Comment: I don't use VM environments, but there is an apache2 and  mysql installation too. Could these cause a problem? I think not but I am not sure.